# Count of multiple columns from a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have total 3 tables

`tbl_projects`,`tbl_bug`,`tbl_bug_history`

i need to display total of 3 counts for each projects.

1.total bug for each projects- this is from `tbl_bug`

2. total count of "invalid", total count of "duplicate"-- this is from bug history

Output should be in the following sample format

---

project name | total bug | invalid | duplicate |

---

### project-one | 5 | 6 |   7   |

Please help me table structure is define below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_bug` ( 
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`project_id` int(10) NOT NULL, 
`bugname` varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;
```

## Dumping data for table `tbl_bug`

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_bug` (`id`, `project_id`, `bugname`) VALUES 
(1, 1, 'first-bug'), 
(2, 1, 'second-bug'), 
(3, 1, 'bug-third'), 
(4, 1, 'bug-four'), 
(5, 1, 'bug-give'), 
(6, 1, 'master-bug'), 
(7, 2, 'error-notice'), 
(8, 3, 'invalid bug'), 
(9, 4, 'insufficinet memory'), 
(10, 4, 'hello bug'); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_bug_history` ( 
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`bug_id` int(10) NOT NULL, 
`status` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=21 ;
```

### Dumping data for table `tbl_bug_history`

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_bug_history` (`id`, `bug_id`, `status`) VALUES 
(2, 1, 'invalid'), 
(3, 2, 'invalid'), 
(6, 3, 'duplicate'), 
(7, 4, 'feedback'), 
(10, 5, 'duplicate'), 
(11, 6, 'duplicate'), 
(12, 6, 'invalid'), 
(13, 7, 'feedback'), 
(14, 7, 'normal'), 
(15, 8, 'duplicate'), 
(16, 8, 'normal'), 
(18, 9, 'feedback'), 
(19, 10, 'invalid'), 
(20, 10, 'feedback'); 



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tbl_projects` ( 
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`projectname` varchar(250) NOT NULL, 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

### Dumping data for table `tbl_projects`

```
INSERT INTO `tbl_projects` (`id`, `projectname`) VALUES 
(1, 'project-one'), 
(2, 'project-two'), 
(3, 'project-three'), 
(4, 'project-four');
```

Comment: you have wrong count in your expected output i thnk

Comment: yes i m getting wrong output

Comment: select proj.id,proj.projectname,count(bugtbl.id) as totalbug,(select count(id) from tbl_bug_history where  bug_id = bugtbl.id and status = 

'invalid'
) as invalidcount    from tbl_projects proj

left join tbl_bug bugtbl on bugtbl.project_id=proj.id  
group by proj.projectname....... this query is giving invalid count as 1 for project-one. But actual result should be 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.This is your expected output I think.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1d756/3

Comment: Thanks  it is working. if i add one more field call field_value in tbl_bug_history  and  condition should be like this status=invalid and field value=20 ,status=duplicate and field value=90.. please suggest what changes i need to make.. once more big thanks Charvee shah :)

Comment: Changes will be done in bugHistory.status in ('invalid','duplicate') line.Instead of this,write this line "(bugHistory.status = 'invalid' and field_value = 20) or (bugHistory.status = 'duplicate' and field_value = 90)"

Comment: Hi Charvee shah.. Can you please give a solution to the below issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29326621/one-to-many-database-result-issue-in-mysql